# Can we add css classes on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, css, shopify

I working on Shopify website by editing. And new css files needed to be added. Created style.css file in assets and connected in theme.liquid file as

```
{{ 'style.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}.
```

I want to know can we add new css classes? If so how can we do it?

Answer (score 0):

And you have to add this to it

```
{
    "type": "text",
    "id": "section_css_class",
    "label": {
      "en": "Section CSS Class"
    },
    "default": {
      "en": "Type your own CSS class"
    }
  },
```

and

```
 <div class="page-width {{ section.settings.section_css_class }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the style of your `class` on CSS by adding `. (period)`. For example, if your HTML has `<div class="this">` you can edit it on the CSS file:

```
.this{
color: white;
}
```

or do you mean, can you add a class in the HTML file? If that is what you mean, then this [link](https://getshogun.com/learn/shopify-custom-css) can help you. You have to switch from the rich text editor to the HTML editor as shown this is image:[image: 3. Switch from the rich text editor to the HTML editor [by Adam Ritchie]]

References: Adam Ritchie, https://getshogun.com/learn/shopify-custom-css